# Is $\{\{1,2,3\},\emptyset\}$ a partition of $\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Title says it all. Is $\{\{1,2,3\},\emptyset\}$ a partition of $\{1,2,3\}$? I'm guessing it isn't, because the definition in [Naive Set Theory](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&lpg=PA28&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=partition&f=false) states the following:

> A partition of $X$ is a disjoint collection $\mathbb{C}$ of non-empty subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thus violates the “non-empty” part of the definition, so no, it’s not a partition according to this definition.